# Javascript failure to generate divs that include XML info. (xml beginner)

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to create a script that will generate divs depending on the information of the XML file that I desire. The issue is that my script does not work at all. What I did was to find the code on w3schools.org and modified it a bit to match what I wanted it to do.

The results:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{ // code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","products.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var size=0;
var i=0;
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("honey");
var y=x.length;
var final=null;

function gethoney()
{
   for (i < y) 
   { 
     a1='<div style="height:200px;width:300px;float:left;background-color:#FFF5CC;opacity:0.7;text-align:center;">';
     a2='<p><b>';
     a3=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
     a4='<br>';
     a5=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
     a6='</br></b></p>';
     a8='</div>';
     a9='<div style="height:200px;width:20px;float:left;"></div>';
     a10='<div style="height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">';
     a11=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
     a12='</div>';
     final=final + a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a8 + a9 + a10 + a11 + a12;
     size=size+300;
     i=i+1;
   }
document.getElementById("mainbody").style.height=size;
size=size-20;
document.getElementById("products").style.height=size;
document.getElementById("products").innerHTML=final;
}
</script>
```

Using final in order to save every single div doesn't seem like an ideal way to me but I did it anyway.

and the XML is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<honey>
   <name>one</name>
   <price>3</price>
   <image><img src=""></img></image>
   <disc>This is a honey</disc>
</honey>
<honey>
   <name>one</name>
   <price>3</price>
   <image><img src=""></img></image>
   <disc>This is a honey</disc>
</honey>
etc etc
```

I tried to find info about this but without any luck. Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong and suggest improvements/corrections? Also, it would be appreciated if someone could write down a way to generate the divs without using *final* to save them and then innerHTML.

Comment: Your XML file is invalid: it can only contain 1 root tag. Wrap your `<honey>` tags inside 1 tag.

Comment: Not adding 1 root tag was a huge mistake from my side which I already fixed but that didn't exactly solve everything.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your xml file is not xml.

2) Change this:

```
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

to this:

```
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
```

2)

```
for (i < y)
```

That's an error.

4) You define a function called gethoney() that you never call.  But you shouldn't call that function until you can get something like this to work:

```
console.log("==>" + xmlDoc[0].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Comment: It works nicely now! I changed `for (x<y)` to `while (x[i])` and it's shown fine. I had a few issues with size as well but I just added `+ 'px'` after it and it's working as intended. The only thing left is to add the code of the picture with XML because what I put in `<image>` was completely wrong by the looks of it.

Comment: Yes, the code inside gethoney() tries to obtain what's between the opening and closing <img> tags, which if you look at your xml is....nothing.  If you want to get the value of the src _attribute_ for the <img> tag, you can get the value by calling getAttribute('src') on the <img> tag, so  x[0].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute('src')

Comment: "what I put in <image> was completely wrong", If you constructed the xml file yourself, why not something like: <image_url>`http://website.com/images/flower.jpg`</image_url>